# Jquery Ajax Request and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

New to Jquery, even newer to Jquery Ajax calls - here is my problem:

I have a small form - email address submit - that fires to a PHP file which inserts the email into a table.

I want to do the following:

1. Handle the form submission through Ajax so there is no refresh
2. After successfully writing to the table I want to change the submit button's text to "Success!" for 3 seconds and then back to
   "Sign Up" with fadeIn and fadeOut effects.

Here is my code for the form:

```
<form action="" id="registerform" name="registerform" method="post" >
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Email Address" onClick="empty()" onBlur="determine()" />
    <button id="join" type="submit" name="join" onClick="validate()">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Here is my terrible attempt at handling the POST request through Jquery:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    $.post('register.php', function() {
            $('#join').html('Success!')             
    });        
    //disable default action
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Can anyone comment on how to make the Ajax request work (doesn't seem to be)?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Alright, the following block of Jquery adds the data to the table, however, my button text does not change:

```
 $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        $.post('register.php', $("#registerform").serialize(), function() {
            $('#join').html('Success!')             
        });        
    //disable default action
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Any ideas now?

Comment: are you getting any errors? What is the final output?

Comment: Zero errors and the PHP file is working properly, I have tested it independent of the Ajax request and it writes successfully.

Comment: Does the button text get changed?

Comment: No, it does not.  So that would mean the request is not completing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of one of my ajax calls

```
details = "sendEmail=true&" + $("form").serialise();

$.ajax({
    url: "yourphppage.php",
    type: "post",
    data: details,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (data == "false") {
            console.log("There is a problem on the server, please try again later");    
        } else {
                //Do something with what is returned
        }
    }
})
```

And on the server side

```
if (isset($_POST['sendEmail'])) {
  //Do something with the data
}
```

Of course this is only an example, and you may need to alter this to suit your needs :)

One thing to note is what `if (data == "false")` does. Well on the server side i can `echo "false"` to tell the ajax call it was not successful.

Comment: This is way more readable than the POST helper method - is there any downside to using this format over helper methods like POST and GET?

Comment: Alright, I'm going to set this up using this method and see what results I get.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually sending any data to the server.  You need to use the 'data' parameter of `$.post` to send your data.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    $.post('register.php', $(this).serialize(), function() {
        $('#join').html('Success!');             
    });        
    //disable default action
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: That helped to get the ajax request to complete, however, the button HTML does not change?

Comment: You can try opening up your network panel and making sure the request went through sucessfully.  Also, try adding a `console.log('success');` into the success callback for $.post to see if the success function is actually being called.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but does the POST request send anything at all? Try adding the data in the POST request.

```
$('form#registerform').submit(function() {
  var email = $(this).find('input[name=email]').val();
  $.post('register.php', {email: email}, function() {
    $('#join').html('Success!');             
  }); 

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Where you're pushing your form data to server in ajax call? change code to this.

```
var data = {$("#email").val()};
$('form').submit(data ,function(e) {
    $.post('register.php', function() {
            $('#join').html('Success!')             
    });        
    //disable default action
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: sending form using http request. same thing as asynchronous process. and follow the code.. not words.

Comment: I get an error on this submission:  missing : after property id
http://localhost/startupwinnipeg.htm
Line 59